# Tomcat 7 - Firefox works but IE doesn't, cookie issue

Tags: tomcat, cookies, session-cookies

I'm trying to solve a problem with Tomcat 7 + IE 9, the following URL request doesn't receive a cookie and I think it's due to the URL and how Tomcat handles it:

http://localhost:8080/chris?screen_name=DO_POLICY_ENQUIRY

My guess is something with the '?'. I was hoping setting FWD_SLASH_IS_SEPARATOR to FALSE will fix this, any ideas?

Firefox works fine, it's just IE. My 'java options' in Tomcat 7 look like this:

-Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0
-Dcatalina.base=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\endorsed
-Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\temp
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\con
 \logging.properties
                                                                                          -Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.http.ServerCookie.FWD_SLASH_IS_SEPARATOR=false

Answer (score 1):

**THE SOLUTION:** sessionCookiePathUsesTrailingSlash="false"

We actually figured out how to solve this. It was a Tomcat 7 setting we needed to set. We placed it in SERVER.XML, under the  tag as follows:

```
<Context path="/test" reloadable="true" docBase="c:\webapp\test" workDir="c:\webapp\test" sessionCookiePathUsesTrailingSlash="false"/>
```

When we were debugging the problem and looking at the cookies path we noticed it was putting a '\' slash after the webapp name.. so for out TEST webapp it was setting
the path to '/test/' instead of '/test'. This caused a bunch of problems.

Has anyone else had to deal with this setting in Tomcat 7? Or have a similar problem?

Comment: I have a similar problem, tried setting that on the context, but did not work for me...

Comment: I was trying on the port 8080, and with IE you need to use http://localhost:8080 instead of localhost:8080, when using a port in IE you need to specify the protocol.